# Spring cloud Gateway and Consul Server

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

Please help. 
I have Spring Cloud Gateway and Consul Server. In Spring Cloud Gateway i'm use  "cloud:gateway:discovery:locator:enabled:true". I can send requests for services registered in the Consul (**ServiceName**). For example URL "/**ServiceName**/foo/bar".
Can I customize Spring Cloud Gateway so that the queries would look like /foo/ bar/**ServiceName**/baz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes [you can](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_configuring_predicates_and_filters_for_discoveryclient_routes)

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates[0].name: Path
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates[0].args[pattern]: "'/foo/bar/'+serviceId+'/**'"
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[0].name: RewritePath
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[0].args[regexp]: "'/' + serviceId + '/foo/bar/(?<remaining>.*)'"
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[0].args[replacement]: "'/${remaining}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

My version for application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      locator:
        enabled: true
        predicates:
          - name: Path
            args:
              pattern: "'/foo/bar/' + serviceId + '/**'"
        filters:
          - name: RewritePath
            args:
              regexp: "'/foo/bar/' + serviceId + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
              replacement: "'/foo/bar/' + serviceId + '/${remaining}'"
```